# I'm a data geek and I want to buy a watch for running, what should I get?

Tags: gps, running

I would like a watch that would give me access to the raw data it records. 
Not some magic transfer to the cloud where graphs are built on the fly for me.

The data-points that I'm interested in are (minimally):

- lap time (or if no laps are detected, consider every kilometer a lap)
- real-time speed
- track recording (through a GPS that can deal with trees and the like)
- real-time altitude.

The screen should at least be able to display at the same time:

- total time
- current lap time

and it should also be light on demand for night runs.

It would be nice to also have pace and heart rate data available, but it's not a must.

And of course, the cheaper the better.
Also I prefer the robust minimalist approach over the gazillion of features but fragile as hell approach.

I never owned such a specialized watch, so my expectations or my demands might be off. 
Feel free to set my feet back on the ground and explain what I should be looking for or what my needs should be.

Comment: Are you open to using an app on a smartphone ?

Comment: @Amine, exactly, those what OP describes is the description of typical running app on smartphone, or GPS. while it is possible to implement it into watch, I don't see a reason why.

Comment: I don't own a smartphone and I'm not planning to buy one any time soon. But even if I did, it would be a burden to carry while running. Do those smartphone apps give access to the data? The ones I've seen on my friend's phone don't.

Comment: It actually sounds like the typical functionality for a runners watch. I wouldn't want it in a phone, but the watch form factor works for me.

Comment: Yes, I ran with a watch quite often. But it's just a dump chronometer. Doesn't even do laps. I think it's time to upgrade :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just bought the 310xt, because it stores a lot of data (does everything you want, but doesn't have a barometric altimeter, just gps altitude). I am very happy with it. Because it is slightly older, the price is very reasonable. 
Many more expensive watches are a bit smaller, but they have a battery that lasts only 8h when new, the 310xt has ample reserve.

More details than you want to know can be found on this webpage http://www.dcrainmaker.com/2009/09/garmin-forerunner-310xt-in-depth-review.html

Comment: Impressive review! But it seems the data has to be fed to a social-website that aggregates and graphs your data for you.

Comment: Most of the Garmins graph your data on the watch realtime as well as being able to get some useful analysis online. There are also various offline options.

Comment: You can directly download the data to your computer without using the social website. It comes with the program ANT Agent that copies the data to your computer.